# need a specific row out of a datatable in a report

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Currently I get 3 rows back from a query, although the report only displays one of those rows. I need all three in the datatable, but only one row to be rendered. How can I choose that row specifically in the report. I'd rather not create another datatable in my dataset just to accommodate this.

```
=FormatCurrency(Fields!tip.Value, "DailySystemFinancialDataSet_tipsCount"))
```

That's what the field looks like, but I want to make sure the row it prints is where Fields!pay_type = 'comp tip'.

EDIT***

Like I said, I don't need to be manipulating these table rows.. the data is collected and calculated, I just need to get a specific row out of the table in the dataset. Everything is already passed to the report, so I'm using the report editor in design mode (vs2008) and I'd like a solution that works within those constraints. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reporting services documentation, finally.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

in particular, the RowNumber() function is exactly what I needed to solve the problem. Thanks ya'll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq, first retrieve all your rows and make a select query in linq to return you the row you want to work with.

```
table.Select(t => t.Id==someId).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

A) Change your query to limit to `where pay_type = 'comptip'`

B)

```
while (result) {
    if (pay_type == 'comptip') { display(); last; }
}
```

Adjust pseudo code to C# as needed.